# How to perform EDA/build a ML model if you have to join 2 tables together?

Tags: machine-learning, join, duplicates, exploratory-data-analysis

Looking for best practices for doing EDA/building a ML model if you have to join 2+ tables together, and it results in many duplicate rows.

It also does not make much sense to just perform EDA/build a ML model on 1 table at a time - joining datasets with other sources seems like a high liklihood event.

For example, lets say I have 2 tables for Airbnb. One has the Airbnb Listings data:

```
{'id': {0: 958, 1: 5858, 2: 8142, 3: 8339, 4: 8739},
 'name': {0: 'Bright, Modern Garden Unit - 1BR/1BTH',
  1: 'Creative Sanctuary',
  2: 'Friendly Room Apt. Style -UCSF/USF - San Francisco',
  3: 'Historic Alamo Square Victorian',
  4: 'Mission Sunshine, with Private Bath'},
 'host_id': {0: 1169, 1: 8904, 2: 21994, 3: 24215, 4: 7149},
 'host_name': {0: 'Holly',
  1: 'Philip And Tania',
  2: 'Aaron',
  3: 'Rosy',
  4: 'Ivan & Wendy'},
 'neighbourhood_group': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'neighbourhood': {0: 'Western Addition',
  1: 'Bernal Heights',
  2: 'Haight Ashbury',
  3: 'Western Addition',
  4: 'Mission'},
 'latitude': {0: 37.77028, 1: 37.74474, 2: 37.76555, 3: 37.77564, 4: 37.7603},
 'longitude': {0: -122.43317,
  1: -122.42089,
  2: -122.45213,
  3: -122.43642,
  4: -122.42197},
 'room_type': {0: 'Entire home/apt',
  1: 'Entire home/apt',
  2: 'Private room',
  3: 'Entire home/apt',
  4: 'Private room'},
 'price': {0: 202, 1: 235, 2: 56, 3: 575, 4: 110},
 'minimum_nights': {0: 2, 1: 30, 2: 32, 3: 9, 4: 1},
 'number_of_reviews': {0: 383, 1: 111, 2: 9, 3: 28, 4: 770},
 'last_review': {0: '2023-02-19',
  1: '2017-08-06',
  2: '2022-10-27',
  3: '2019-06-28',
  4: '2023-02-25'},
 'reviews_per_month': {0: 2.31, 1: 0.66, 2: 0.09, 3: 0.17, 4: 4.65},
 'calculated_host_listings_count': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 13, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'availability_365': {0: 128, 1: 365, 2: 365, 3: 365, 4: 159},
 'number_of_reviews_ltm': {0: 59, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 34},
 'license': {0: 'City Registration Pending',
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: 'STR-0000264',
  4: 'STR-0000028'}}
```

Lets say the 2nd table has Review data, where each review has a unique `review_id`, the `listing_id` its tied to (what you would join with), `date_of_review`, `reviewer_id`, and other useful/predictive columns such as `word_count_of_review`, `age_of_reviewer`, `n_stars_given`, `length_of_stay`, `would_rec_to_a_friend`, etc.

```
{'listing_id': {0: 958, 1: 958, 2: 958, 3: 958, 4: 958},
 'date': {0: '2009-07-23',
  1: '2009-08-03',
  2: '2009-09-27',
  3: '2009-11-05',
  4: '2010-02-13'},
  ...}
```

How would I use the data in both tables but not have my EDA/ML model all messed up due to multiple rows?

Comment: I believe your question could be solved by some intense feature engineering, I am going to drop some ideas from the top of my head: combine the reviews (for the stars get the mean, for the age, drop outliers and get the mean as well, for the review, I would merge them all and do a list of important words then one_hot encode them,